Putting Mergefields in headers make them invisible
I am trying to insert a Mail Merge mergefield into the header portion of my word document but it turns invisible everytime I click out of the header editing. If I reenter the header selection and right click and update field it is visible again until I click out again. I use an excel sheet as my existing list of recipients and if I copy and paste the exact same mergefield outside it works fine so it probably has nothing to do with not being able to get that column. I have tried using control+f9 and typing out { MERGEFIELD Name } as well as using the insert mergefield button. Any idea what's causing this issue?
Edit: I think this is caused by having more {Next Record} then actual rows in an excel. Any reasons why this might be the cause?

I don't think mergefields are supported in the header and footer of a page as these are copied to each page with specific rules, and have their own formatting rules.

Mergefields only work in headers for certain types of merge (e.g. Letter merge, but not Directory Merge). It is to do with the potential of having more than one data source record on a page. You may be able to put the MERGEFIELD in a paragraph in the body, with a unique paragraph style, and use a STYLEREF field to reference that paragraph in the header.
